# GAE Node.js api memory peak during PDF creation for email sending

Tags: node.js, pdf, google-app-engine, memory-leaks, sendgrid

I have MERN app for selling event tickets, and it uses SendGrid API to send confirmation and PDF tickets via e-mail. It is hosted on Google App Engine, a service for the React frontend and another one for the Node.js backend.

I was having problems when users bought +5 tickets on a single order: GAE logs told me the service hit the soft memory limit, and to solve it I had to upgrade to instance_class: F4. While this worked, I think my code is using too much memory on PDF generation, this is the function that handles it:

```
const sendTickets = (tickets, msg, orderId, emailSent, res, data) => {
  if (!emailSent) {
    let html = fs.readFileSync(
      path.join(__dirname + '../../../config/ticketTemplate.html'),
      'utf8'
    );
    let options = {
      height: '266px',
      width: '660px',
    };
    Promise.all(
      tickets.map((ticket) => {
        return pdf.create(
          {
            html: html,
            data: ticket,
            path: `Ticket ${ticket.name}.pdf`,
            type: 'buffer',
          },
          options
        );
      })
    )
      .then((result) => {
        const msgData = {
          to: msg.to,
          from: /* site email */,
          templateId: /* sendgrid template */,
          dynamicTemplateData: {
            s: msg.s,
            title: msg.title,
            date: msg.date,
            time: msg.time,
            name: msg.name,
            place: msg.place,
          },
          attachments: result.map((ticket, index) => {
            return {
              content: Buffer.from(ticket).toString('base64'),
              filename: `Ticket ${index}.pdf`,
              type: 'application/pdf',
              disposition: 'attachment',
            };
          }),
        };
        sgMail
          .send(msgData)
          .then(() => {
            Order.findByIdAndUpdate(orderId, { emailSent: true }).then(() =>
              res.json(data)
            );
          })
          .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err);
            res.error(400).json(err);
          });
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
        res.status(400).send(error);
      });
  } else {
    res.json(data);
  }
};
```

Various API endpoints can trigger ticket email sending, so I extracted this function that takes an array of tickets data, the message data, an order ID, emailSent boolean, the express res object and some order data. I'm using pdf-creator-node to generate the PDF, as it correctly parses css fonts and flex/grid I use on the ticket template, other solutions didn't render correctly.

As I understand it, I'm not handling memory correctly, and there must be a better way to do it, I can't figure out a better approach. Can you help me? Thank you!

Comment: The memory issue doesn't seem to have anything to do with sending emails and instead relates to PDF generation.  It would be helpful if you could rewrite your question to focus on the actual problem.

Comment: This definitely seems to be an issue with the size of the PDF you are creating. How big is a single PDF ticket? Is that something you can reduce?